# ASP.NET and WCF Service hosting under IIS application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis-7.5, wcf-data-services, wcf-hosting

[image]

In my application have requirement, to setup a website and webservice in a same domain so I have to create one WebSite for example ABCWebSite (which is a .NET MVC application) and under the ABCWebSite I wanted to host an ABCService which is a WCF web service. I have followed the same. But I am getting following issue.

**Configuration Error** 
**Description**: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message**: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
       </serviceBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
```

Please let me what i am missing or is this approach is good to go.

Heaps Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Have you added this as Virtual directory ?

Comment: Yes, ABCService is a virtual directory.Or do i need to Add Application.

Comment: Yes try adding it as application and it should work.

Comment: Getting below mentioned error
Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].